# How to locate Latitude and  Longitude

Tags: c++

I have a device that is connected to the internet. The objective is to be able to locate the latitude and longitude of the device from the internet. 
So I need to implement a code in C++ that would use the internet to find out the latitude and longitude. The device does not have a GPS. So just through an internet connection how do I go about to find the location of the device.
I tried to look for answers but most of them relate to an iphone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What information do you have to start with that you are trying to convert to lat/long?

Comment: Do you want 1 answer that works both for C and C++, or 2 different answers: one for each of the 2 different languages?

Comment: Are you trying to obtain the lat/long for your product / device using the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do without access to some sort of location based service (some use GPS, but some e.g. triangulate known WiFi hotspots) is to geolocate the IP address.  Typically that will get you within 20-30 miles, but in some cases you can be very far off (e.g. if the IP is a proxy server far removed from the actual user, as is the case for example with all AOL customers).

There are a number of services available for geolocating an IP address.  [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/) is one I have used before.

Comment: Thanks this was the quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

check out Google Maps API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html